# Sleep mode differences between systemctl and pm-suspend?

Tags: suspend, power-management, systemd, resume

I'm trying to run a script in `/etc/pm/sleep.d` on resume from sleep. I'm not seeing any indication that the script ever gets run when I sleep the machine with "`systemctl suspend`". I do see that when I use "`pm-suspend`" to sleep the machine the script does get executed.

Whats the difference between systemctl and pm-suspend? Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 6):

See [the power management page on the Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_management#Sleep_hooks).

systemd does not use `pm-utils` to put the machine to sleep when using `systemctl suspend`, `systemctl hibernate` or `systemctl hybrid-sleep`; `pm-utils` hooks, including any custom hooks, will not be run.